# Why did my virtual machine VBS scripting stop working after upgrading to Windows 8.1?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, windows-8.1

The scripts shown below worked fine in Windows 8 for months.  The first script is a batch file that calls the second script.  I have a 'start' and 'stop' set of scripts as well.  I used these to start and stop a series of VM servers that needed to start in a delayed order.  This 'status' pair of scripts shown below is the shorter of the three and should be enough to communicate what I was doing.

Obviously I'm not a script guru; I put these together after viewing a variety of examples and they worked OK for what I wanted.

I just upgraded to Windows 8.1 and the scripts no longer work.  They just 'fall' through, meaning the .vbs doesn't perform any commands.

Could anyone suggest what may be the problem?  Do I have to restart something after the upgrade because it doesn't start automatically?  I didn't recall having to start WMI to initially get these to operate, but I did this some time ago and may have forgotten.  I didn't want to start doing things until I knew for certain what happened.

Thanks.

Best Regards,
Alan

Batch file:

```
@echo off
cscript c:\batchFiles\vmStatus.vbs
echo.
echo vmStatus.vbs completed
echo.
pause
```

.vbs file

```
Option Explicit

Dim WMIService
Dim VMList
Dim VM

'Get instance of 'virtualization' WMI service on the local computer
Set WMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\virtualization")

'Get all the MSVM_ComputerSystem object
Set VMList = WMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Msvm_ComputerSystem")

For Each VM In VMList
   WScript.Echo "========================================"
   WScript.Echo "VM Caption: " & VM.Caption
   WScript.Echo "VM Name: " & VM.ElementName
   WScript.Echo "VM GUID: " & VM.Name
   WScript.Echo "VM State: " & VM.EnabledState
Next
```

Comment: Does the VBScript run at all? Try adding a line `WScript.Echo "foo"` after `Option Explicit` and see if that message is shown.

Comment: Yes, 'foo' displays.  Immediately after 'foo' was the following:    `c:\batchFiles\vmStatus.vbs(15, 1) (null): 0x80041010` and then `vmStatus.vbs completed` followed by `Press any key to continue...`.

Comment: Error 0x80041010 means "invalid class". This may be a stupid question, but did you actually install the Hyper-V role on that machine?

Comment: If everything is properly installed, checking the state of WMI with something like [WBEMtest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692770.aspx) or [WMIDiag](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/02/03/wmidiag-2-1-is-here.aspx) might be a good starting point. Also consider [rebuilding the WMI repository](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2009/04/13/wmi-rebuilding-the-wmi-repository.aspx).

Comment: Re Hyper-V role, I think the answer is yes, but maybe you're asking something I'm assuming... I've been running 3 virtual servers for months.  I initially started with Hyper-V Manager, but I got tired of starting the VM's manually, so I added the scripts.  Does that address your question?

Comment: Re check of WMI: WBENtext ran, but I wouldn't know what to look for.  WMIDiag won't run on Win 8.1 64 bit.  Rebuilding WMI comes w/ a warning.  Is WMI a service that must be started, or is it always running?

Comment: Yes, the service "Window Management Instrumentation" (`Winmgmts`) should always be running and should be configured for automatic startup. As for `WBEMtest`, the first things to look at would be if you're able to resolve the `/root/virtualization` namespace and a class `Msvm_ComputerSystem` in it. However, this question is getting rather off-topic for SO. [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place for troubleshooting WMI issues.

Comment: Just to close out this comment thread, I finally saw that in fact `Winmgmts` was running.  Not sure why I didn't see it earlier because it is clearly a critical service.  Anyway, final answer to my original post is given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to why the script stopped working is that the namespace to access the service changed from Win 8 to Win 8.1.  The line below shows the proper namespace to set WMIService.

```
Set WMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\virtualization\v2")
```

This link to my [MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/890c38fa-b689-4df2-a07c-f6f4ce0472f4/vbs-scripting-seems-to-have-stopped-after-upgrading-to-windows-81?forum=ITCG) shows additional details.

Thanks Ansgar for your help because you got me pointed in the right area.

Best Regards,
Alan